# How can I merge both the inner border to make it one broad line in the middle of the circle?

Tags: angular, css

I am trying to make something like this

[image]

as it is dynamic in nature so I think I should use table for this but I got stuck at the point where I have to merge both the inner lines into one and pass it through all circles. How can I merge both the inner border to make it one broad line in the middle of the circle?

Embed link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdm29t?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html
Editor link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fb3bnc

Comment: That link doesn't appear to work. I get `Fatal error: External resource failed to load:`

Comment: hi @user184994, I made another link. can you please tell if this link is working?   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fb3bnc

Comment: Yep, that one works

Comment: I forgot to add css. new link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fb3bnc

Comment: Don't link to your code, *show us your code*: include the [mcve] code required to demonstrate/reproduce your problem *in* your question (currently there are three votes to close your question based on the absence of code, one of which is mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try Pseudo-elements? Do it with `::before` and `::after` and remove border of 2nd `td`. Hope this helps you :)

```css
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.circle {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px 40px; 
    background: #dddddd;
    width: 1px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}

.circle::before {    
    background-color: #a1a1a1;
    width: 2px;
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 48%;
    content: "";
    top: -58%;}
  
.circle::after {    
    background-color: #a1a1a1;
    width: 2px;
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 48%;
    content: "";
    bottom: -55%;}
    
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;

}

th,
td {
  padding: 0px;
}

td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2){
border-right: none;
}

td:nth-child(3),td:nth-child(2){
border-left: none;
}

button {
margin-left:210px;
}

.payment-summary {
 font-family: 'Roboto',
 'Helvetica Neue',
 sans-serif;
 color: #008b8b;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="50%"></th>
    <th class="icon"></th>
    <th width="50%"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11 july 2017
<br>
3:45 PM
    </td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cleveland</td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look. To achieve what you want, you can drop the middle cell and add the circle in the first cell. Then position the circle on the right border line.

[You can find the code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxqjpg)

What I did, was make the cells position relative and the circles position absolute and position them the way you want it.

```
<!-- language: css -->
.circle {
  border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding: 10px 40px; 
  background: #dddddd;
  width: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  right:-43px;
  top: -15px; 
}

th,
td {
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

And edited the html, so that the circles are in the first cell.

```
<!-- language: html -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <th width="50%"></th>
    <th width="50%"></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      11 july 2017
      <br>
      3:45 PM
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lois
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>$150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>$300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Cleveland
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </td>
    <td>$250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

**updated the link